openldap: add simple attributes to users via ldif?
How can I add some simple attributes to users in openldap using ldif and ldapadd/ldapmodify?
I would like each user/person to have optional mail, middle_name and city attributes.
using the follwing ldif:
dn: cn=john,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
cn: john
sn: John
mail: john@john.com

with:
ldapadd -f john.ldif

prints:
adding new entry "cn=john,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com"
ldap_add: Object class violation (65)
    additional info: attribute 'mail' not allowed


The mail attribute is provided by inetOrgPerson (which is the child of organizationalPerson, child of person), so you need to add the 2 missing objectClass. I don't know for the other 2 attributes, are you sure there exists a schema that defines them, and are you using such schema ?

I want to define my own schema. Those are just examples. I will need more custom fields  as well.


I want to define my own schema

Then you have to start by defining a schema.

Define the attributeTypes that you want.
Define the objectClasses that would contain those attributes.
Assign the needed objectClasses to your entries.

OpenLDAP stores its schema as part of configuration – if you're using slapd.conf, then you have to add attributetype and objectclass statements; and if you're using cn=config, then you have to insert olcAttributeType and olcObjectClass attributes.
See /etc/openldap/schema for a ton of examples.
In general, though, you should try to use existing schema objects if they fit – e.g. you already have the mail attribute, and you already have the l aka localityName attribute to specify the city (see core.schema), as well as the postalAddress attribute, the street attribute, etc.; and you can already use those just by changing your entries from the 'person' objectClass to the organizationalPerson or inetOrgPerson subclass.
If the existing attributes don't fit, you'll have to define your own – or import some definitions from a different system, such as Active Directory.
One complication is that each attribute or objectClass needs an OID (e.g. the l field is internally known as 2.5.4.7), and OID trees were originally assigned through various International Standards Organizations. You can get an OID for free through IANA – sign up for a Private Enterprise Number]1 and then you'll get to use 1.3.6.1.4.1.xxxxx as the basis for your OIDs – but it's still a bit of extra trouble. Alternatively, the "Active Directory approach" would be to randomly generate an OID under Microsoft's dedicated subtree.
(Of course, if you import an attribute from AD, you can just use the OID that AD uses for it, as long as your definition is mostly compatible.)
Once you have your OID base, you can start defining attributes, using the *.schema files as an example. For example, if you think storing the middle name as a discrete field is a necessary, then you would start with this (LDAP universally uses camelCase for names, so it would be called middleName, not middle_name):
attributetype ( <oid-goes-here> NAME 'middleName'
                                DESC 'Udi: The middle name of a person.'
                                <syntax, cardinality, equality, ordering...> )

For a "middle name" field I would probably use 2.16.840.1.113730.3.1.34 per the AD definition as the OID here. For OpenLDAP, the OID doesn't actually matter all that much, it's the name that matters – do not rename attributes that are in use as it will break indexing and searching.
You can, if necessary, define aliases for an attribute; for example, the 'sn' field is actually defined as NAME ( sn surname ). However, even if you do this, do not change the "primary" name –  extending NAME a to NAME ( a b ) is fine, but trying to turn it into NAME ( b a ) still counts as renaming and breaks stuff!)
While all LDAP attributes are byte strings, the SYNTAX parameter defines their interpretation – e.g. an ASCII string, a UTF-8 string, an ASCII integer, a binary blob, etc. In most cases you can go with 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 which is DirectoryString or a UTF-8 Unicode string, with {max} to specify the maximum length. For all intents and purposes, it is compatible with the "UnicodeString" 2.5.5.12 that Active Directory uses.
( ... SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{1024} )

You also need to explicitly define the matching rules for the attribute – should it be case-sensitive or not? should it support substring search or not? For example, the LDAP server has built-in support for matching telephone numbers in a way that ignores whitespace (so 555 12 12 matches 555-1212). In most cases, you'll just want a basic string equality and substring match:
( ... EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
      SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch )

Finally, you can use SINGLE-VALUE if the attribute should be unique per entry; otherwise multiple values are allowed.
( ... SINGLE-VALUE )

And as a shortcut, you can inherit those parameters from another attribute definition, such as how many core.schema attributes inherit from the name attribute:
( ... SUP name )

So the definition for a middle name field would look either like this:
attributetype ( <oid> NAME 'middleName'
                      DESC 'Udi: The middle name of a person.'
                      SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{1024}
                      EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
                      SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch )

or like this:
attributetype ( <oid> NAME 'middleName'
                      DESC 'Udi: The middle name of a person.'
                      SUP name )

Once the attribute has been defined, in order to use it in an entry you need to define an objectClass that contains that attribute. There are three options:

You can define an auxiliary class that can be attached to just about any entry, such as udiExtraFields, to provide some "extra" attributes.

You can define a structural class that is a subclass of the original class you were using and simply adds some more attributes. For example, person is a structural class, inetOrgPerson is a subclass (and therefore also a structural class), and you could define udiPerson as a subclass of that.

You can define a brand new structural class that is not a subclass of 'person' (i.e. only a subclass of 'top', the base class for everything). This is the least-recommended option, as many tools will expect user accounts to be inetOrgPerson-like.


Each entry has only one structural class that cannot be changed easily, but any number of auxiliary classes that can be added/removed at any time.
( ... SUP top AUXILIARY )
( ... SUP inetOrgPerson STRUCTURAL )

Object classes are where you define which attributes an entry MAY have, and which ones it MUST have. For example, 'mail' might be listed under MUST while 'middleName' and 'streetAddress' would be MAY. (I've seen places define middleName as a required field, but in my little corner of Europe it would be utterly nonsensical to do so, hence MAY.)
( ... MUST ( attr $ anotherAttr $ thirdAttr )
      MAY ( anOptionalAttr $ someOtherAttr )

ldapns.schema has a few short examples of an auxiliary objectClass, and yours might look like this:
objectclass ( <oid> NAME 'udiPersonExtra'
                    DESC 'Udi: Auxiliary class for additional person information'
                    SUP top
                    AUXILIARY
                    MUST ( mail )
                    MAY ( middleName $ streetAddress ) )

whereas if you wanted a structural class, it would be:
objectclass ( <oid> NAME 'udiPerson'
                    DESC 'Udi: Structural class that extends inetOrgPerson'
                    SUP inetOrgPerson
                    STRUCTURAL
                    MUST ( mail )
                    MAY ( middleName $ streetAddress ) )

Finally, once you've got the attribute and objectClass definitions in place, you can start adding them to entries:
dn: cn=whatever
objectClass: udiPerson
sn: whatever
middleName: whatever
mail: whatever

